# Snap install of libreoffice, no mailcap entries

Tags: libreoffice, snap

After installing libreoffice under ubuntu 18.04 as snap application I noticed that it didn't add any entries to mailcap. (What a deb install would do.) Is there any way to add those entries automatically -- except uninstalling the snap application and installing the debs?